# How to add a class if the number of rows in a table is some number with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add class to `div` if the number of rows in the table is larger than 3.

This is my code.

```js
$('.box').each(function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    if ($this.find('tbody > tr').length > 3) {
        $this.find('.box').addClass('newclass');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >1</th>
                <th >2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem1</td>
                    <td>ipsum1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem2</td>
                    <td>ipsum2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem3</td>
                    <td>ipsum3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem4</td>
                    <td>ipsum4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I don't see why this code not working, can somebody try to help me with this?

What I try to achieve is this:

```
<div class="box newclass">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because `this` is a reference to the `.box` element itself. When you do a `find()` from there you're looking for child elements, so nothing it returned. To fix the issue just remove the `find()` call.

However you can make the jQuery more succinct by simply using the `:has()` selector to retrieve `.box` elements which have more than 3 `tr` within them:

```js
$('.box:has(tbody > tr:eq(3))').addClass('newclass');
```

```css
.newclass { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem1</td>
        <td>ipsum1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem2</td>
        <td>ipsum2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem3</td>
        <td>ipsum3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem4</td>
        <td>ipsum4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem1</td>
        <td>ipsum1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you already set the `$this` to the selector. and by now using `$this.find` will try to find inside the element itself, so u can use `$this` directly or search the document itself `$(document).find` instead of `$this.find` >>> try the button to show classes list

```js
$('.box').each(function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    if ($this.find('tbody > tr').length > 3) {
        $(document).find('.box').addClass('newclass');
}
   
});
    $('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(document).find('.box').attr('class'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >1</th>
                <th >2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem1</td>
                    <td>ipsum1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem2</td>
                    <td>ipsum2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem3</td>
                    <td>ipsum3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem4</td>
                    <td>ipsum4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button> show classes list </button>
```